# How can I scrape the correct number of URLs from an infinite-scroll webpage?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, infinite-scroll

I am trying to scrape URLs from a webpage. I am using this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import urllib2 

url = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.barneys.com/barneys-new-york/men/clothing/shirts/dress/classic#sz=176&pageviewchange=true")

content = url.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

links=soup.find_all("a", {"class": "thumb-link"})

for link in links:

      print (link.get('href'))
```

But what I'm getting as output is just 48 links instead of 176. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The website has an infinite scroll on it so that is correct of the script to be returning only 48, because that is all the website loads when it first loads without anyone scrolling

Comment: @user3100115 because if you click on the site, its says `176` products

Comment: So what should I do in order to get all 176 urls?

Comment: Trying to work on it

Comment: Using regular expression would help? If yes, please write me the code for it. I would be very thankful to you.

Comment: You might need to switch to a tool with Javascript support, or duplicate the network requests manually.

Answer (score 2):

So what I did is I used Postmans interceptor feature to look at the call the website made each time it loaded the next set of 36 shirts. Then from there replicated the calls in code. You can't dump it all 176 items all at once so I replicated the 36 at a time the website did.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

urls = []

for i in range(1, 5):
    offset = 36 * i
    r = requests.get('http://www.barneys.com/barneys-new-york/men/clothing/shirts/dress/classic?start=1&format=page-element&sz={}&_=1434647715868'.format(offset))
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)

    links = soup.find_all("a", {"class": "thumb-link"})

    for link in links:
        if len(urls) < 176:
            print (link.get('href'))
            urls.append(link.get('href'))
```

Comment: Do you expect the OP to know exactly how many items are on each page?

Comment: No and I dont either but do 36 items at a time, like their website does. And if the OP really wants to use another network call, he can use the url he was using before and parse out how many products there are supposed to be and use that instead of 176. I didnt feel like doing that.

Comment: Hey Thanks a lot. One more question I have is that how should I get that url which you are using for scraping other webpages?

Comment: I used Postmans interceptor to see the calls the website was making and loading the shirt pictures from. You can use wireshark or Fiddler to see similar network traffic to get the urls they are using in the future

Comment: One problem with this code is that its repeating many urls. How do I solve this?